# Intuition regarding how tension works

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Here is a mock scenario I have to illustrate my confusion,the regular basic assumptions here apply ie smooth floor so there is no friction and air resistance, and a inextensible string . There is a force of 60 N acting on block 2, the tension, however, will be a lot lot lower than 60 N ie the force pulling block 1 would be a lot lower than 60 N, and i only know this purely from common sense but I don't know the intuition behind it, i  don't think F=ma isn't really an intuitive explanation for it either,more so a mathematical proof behind the intuition.

I initially thought, well the tension is low because only a low force is required to get block 1 to the overall acceleration of the system, but that's basically another way of saying $F=ma$ and I'm also kind of suggesting that the tension is ***due to the*** acceleration ,almost like the tension is caused by the acceleration ie acceleration came first and tension is trying to find the right force to cause the block to match the same rate of acceleration of the whole system , but that's obviously not the right chain of events.

My second thought of intuition was the tension force is distributing the force on both objects based on mass such that the ratio of the mass to resultant force on both objects should be equal. But I'm not sure if this is a good intuitive explanation as to why the tension is very low
I see the formula F=ma as proof to the intuition of why the tension is very low , my issue is I don't fully understand the intuition ie its not obvious to me , if someone could provide a better explanation id be grateful.

Comment: This is *obviously* a conceptual question. Please do **not** vote to close it as a "homework-like question or a check-my-work question focused on a specific computation instead of the underlying physics concepts".

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with "acceleration X is **due to** force Y" or "force Y is **due to** force X."  In many cases you can get away with it, but not always.  I recommend remembering your F=ma equation with one additional symbol: $\Sigma F=ma$.  The *sum* of the forces on an object is proportional to the acceleration of that object (the constant of proportionality being $m$).

This summation is important.  In your example block 1 has exactly one force applied to it, which means you kinda-sorta get away with saying either its acceleration is due to the force of tension or that the force of tension is due to its acceleration.  However, in the example of block 2, there are two forces.  You have the tension force and the 60N pulling force in the opposite direction.  In this case you cannot say the tension is due to the acceleration or the acceleration is due to the tension (or the acceleration is due to the pulling).  If you really wanted to say something like that, you'd have to say "the acceleration is due to the sum of the effects of the 60N pulling force and the tension force."

This is really important in your example, because the best place to crack this intuition you have about the tensions is by looking at block 2, where the "due to" notation sort of gets in the way.  It's better to think of it the way Newton thought of it, as "proportional to" rather than "due to."  The accelerations and sum-of-forces are proportional. The accelerations and sum-of-forces go together.  Where one goes, the other goes too, and vice versa.

So how do we see the intuition?  Well, intuitively the blocks must be accelerating.  We'll back up that intuition in a moment, but your wording implies you intuitively understand that there's acceleration here.  $\Sigma F=ma$ has a very intuitive implication.  If acceleration is non-zero, *the forces must be unequal*.  If acceleration is non-zero, the sum of the forces must be non-zero too (numerically, they must sum to $\frac a m$).

And thus you have an intuitive argument for why the tension is not equal to 60N.  For block 2 to be accelerating, the forces must be unequal.  T cannot be 60N.  And, in fact, since our intuition should tell us that the blocks are accelerating to the right, the sum of the forces must be to the right as well, so the tension must be *less than* 60N.

From there its probably a good idea to start really crunching the numbers with $\Sigma F=ma$ on both block 1 and block 2, and you can solve those to figure out what the actual tension force is.  But the above argument indicates at the very least that it's less than 60N

Comment: so would you say my comment about the ratio of the mass and resultant force of each object being equal , is wrong ?
Additionally I just find using ΣF=ma as a form of intuition akin to "what came first the chicken or the egg", ie if I did not know about ΣF=ma how would you show me (not in a mathematical proof sense, more like "common sense" )that it makes sense that the tension in the string would be much lower than 60N ,I don't know like by paralleling into some in real life scenario? etc.

Comment: I think I may have skimmed over that part, so sorry for not addressing it.  If you define the "resultant force" as the equivalent to the sum of all forces on the object, then your statement is correct.  I'm a bit hesistant on the notation only because if you replace "sum of forces" with the "resultant force," it also obscures the next step you need to come to the conclusion that the tension is lower than 60N.  You need the fact that you are summing the forces to get to the next step.  If your mind can comfortably make that leap then, "resultant force" works fine.

Comment: Because right now the entire intuition behind why the tension is really low is based solely on ΣF=ma, but surely someone would know that the tension would be much lower even without knowing of the formula ΣF=ma?In my head ΣF=ma is proof of a already preexisting notion/intuition(which i dont know) like most things in physics

Comment: And actually it *is* somewhat circular.  If you look at how Newton constructed his laws of physics, he *defined* forces to be something with certain properties on objects (such as causing acceleration).  He invented the concept (based on less formal constructions others had, of course).  So it becomes a bit circular because you started with a pulling force *defined* to be 60N, and doubling back on its effect on the objects.

Comment: So the neat thing about $\Sigma F=ma$ is that intuition guided about it works almost everywhere (works everywhere on human scales).  Before it, we might have dozens of intuitions about how blocks behave, how strings behave, how we pull on things, etc.  Intuition about how a person moves might be unrelated to intuition about how a large ship moves on the ocean.  Liquids were thought of differently than solids.  Newton's laws are powerful because once you develop an intuition about how to apply them, they can be used to *reason* about a great many things, predicting what will happen.

Comment: And perhaps there's a difference in meaning here as well.  In many domains, "intuition" refers to what you know to be true and don't have to reason about it at all.  You intuit that the tension is low because you've lived many years, and have some intuition of what happens.  What we are doing know might be called 'reasoning,' where we're trying to explain what happens with respect to a set of rules that we agree upon.  In physics, however, the word takes on a slightly different meaning.  In physics, it refers to trying to figure out what happens without having to crunch the numbers.

Comment: ... and its important to do that because sometimes numbers can lie (especially when you use one slightly wrong by accident).  In physics, "intution" tells us where the result should be, because we can talk about fuzzy things like "unbalanced forces" without having to specify exactly how unbalanced they are.  It lets us speak to broad ranges of problems at once. For example, your example has a 1kg and a 100kg block and a 60N force, but the intuitive approach (aka "reasoning" as used in other domains) lets us say the tension will be less than the pulling force for *any* pair of blocks and force.

Comment: If we want to talk to "intuition" as in other domains, the problem would need to shift.  We wouldn't be able to talk about a "pulling force" or a "tension" measured in Newtons.  We'd have to talk about pulling two blocks on a string, and use "tension" in the vernacular -- perhaps like a sailor might when feeling how taught the ropes holding their sails are.  And then it would be hard to answer it on this particular forum, because now we've had to depart physics entirely -- we've intentionally declared we aren't going to use any of the mainstream physics we've built up over centuries.

Comment: A fun topic for sure.  And a good one if you don't want to trust science on blind faith (I don't.. it has to earn its trust).  But certainly outside of scope.  You could ask specific questions on the History of Math and Science exchange.  Questions like "how did scientists think of 'tension' before Newton" often lead to fascinating replies there.  One can also ask questions about the philosophy of science on the Philosophy stack exchange or read about it on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (I love that site)

Comment: "...The sum of the forces..." also is sometimes called the _net_ force.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Agreed, although here that gets in the way, and I've seen it get in the way before.  It's a bit counterintuitive to combine all of the forces into one net force in one step, and then the only way to proceed in the next step is to immediately break them back apart, to get back to exactly where we started.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really answering the question that you asked—Cort Ammon did a great job of that—but here is, maybe, a different approach to solving the original problem.

The two blocks must move together like one object, and their total mass is 101kg. I would calculate the acceleration, $a$, that would be imparted to the 101kg mass by a 60N force. Then, I would calculate, what force, $f_t$, would be required to impart that same acceleration, $a$, to just the 1kg mass.

$f_t$ must be the tension in the string because the tension in the string is the *only* force that accelerates the smaller object.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial thought is correct. It is  based on the fact that the mass of block 2 is much less than block 1 so it requires much less force to give it the same acceleration as block 1, as they both must have the same acceleration since they are connected together by the string.

But you should verify this by applying Newton’s second law first to the combination of the two blocks and then to block 1 only where the only horizontal force acting on it is the tension in the string.

Hope this helps.